# Summation of Binomial Coefficient Proof

Tags: proof-writing, binomial-coefficients

Prove that $$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k {{n}\choose{k}} = 0$$

I have no idea about how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem), we know that $$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k {{n}\choose{k}} =\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k \times 1^{n-k} {{n}\choose{k}} =(1+(-1))^{n}= 0$$
We have the desired result. Also note that elementary sums involving binomial coefficients usually involves the binomial theorem.